# Unsure why casting is required in this Typescript code. My derp, or language limitation?

Tags: generics, typescript, bluebird, definitelytyped

I'm using the typings (DefinitelyTyped) definitions for bluebird and I'm running into an issue with `Promise.attempt<T>`.

I don't understand why I need the following cast:
https://github.com/brandf/upstream/blob/0b38a42a/src/domain.ts#L73

```
return Promise.attempt<Data>(() => {
    return <Data>handler(matchResult, id);
});
```

Note that handler's type returns `Data|Promise<Data>`.  Without casting the return value to `<Data>` I get the following error:

```
src/domain.ts(72,50): error TS2345: Argument of type '() => Data |
Promise<Data>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Data'.
  Type 'Data | Promise<Data>' is not assignable to type 'Data'.
    Type 'Promise<Data>' is not assignable to type 'Data'.
```

This would make sense if the signature for attempt only took a function that returned data, but there are two overloads.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bluebird/bluebird.d.ts#L57-L58

```
attempt<T>(fn: () => PromiseLike<T>, args?: any[], ctx?: any): Promise<T>;
attempt<T>(fn: () => T, args?: any[], ctx?: any): Promise<T>;
```

My expectation is that Typescript would see both overloads and recognize that `() => Data|Promise<Data>` is the same as `() => Data` plus `() => Promise<Data>`, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Am I missing something?  Is this a limitation of Typescript or simply poor type definitions?

I can modify the bluebird type definitions to have one overload that takes `() => T|Promise<T>` then I don't need the cast, but I'd still like to understand why it's necessary given the existing overloads.

Answer (score 1):

[As Martin points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35185367/4386952), the problem is that TypeScript can't automatically figure out how to decompose that union type, or to compose the overloads, and see that they're compatible in this instance. Really the problem is with the type definitions for bluebird. Instead of having two overloads:

```
attempt<T>(fn: () => PromiseLike<T>, args?: any[], ctx?: any): Promise<T>;
attempt<T>(fn: () => T, args?: any[], ctx?: any): Promise<T>;
```

It should be rewritten as

```
attempt<T>(fn: () => T | PromiseLike<T>, args?: any[], ctx?: any): Promise<T>;
```

I've sent out [a pull request to DefinitelyTyped to fix this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/7960) and some similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for your issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1805. :-)